# How to handle attr method by using jquery migrate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.9.1.js and Jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js in my master page

Below is my code its not working:

```
if ($('#checkbxID').attr('checked')==true) {
}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('#checkbxID').is(':checked');
```

Comment: The above code returns true if the checkbox is checked or false if not.

Comment: Thats right but he asked especially for attr. But +1 for the right solution here, special for the given example.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply..I cant change the code there are bunch of code like this in the project..actually it was working fine when i was using jquery-1.4.1 but now I need to upgrade my jquery from 1.4.1 to 1.9 so i am using jquery 1.9.1 and jquery-migrate-1.4.1 everything is working fine except this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop` instead of `attr`. And there is no need for `== true`.

```
if ( $('#checkbxID').prop('checked') ) {
    // your actions ...
}
```

Comment: I cant change the code..actually it was working fine when i was using jquery-1.4.1 but now I need to upgrade my jquery from 1.4.1 to 1.9 so i am using jquery 1.9.1 and jquery-migrate-1.4.1 everything is working fine except this.

Comment: It is not working and you don't want to change anything. So how should we help you? @WasimShaikh

Comment: its working when I was using only jquery-1.4.1. it doesn't work after updating jquery 1.9.1...so I put jquery-migrate-1.4.1 also in the page, everything gets handled by using jquery migrate except this...do you know about any migrate version of jquery that handle this?or any patch file?@eisbehr

Comment: There were changes tn `attr` on 1.6. You have to change the code to get a wide support of this check. Otherwise don't update. It is not patchable, because it is correct like I showed. And because you will not change the code, you have to stick with 1.4 (*what is hundred years old*). @WasimShaikh

Comment: I know attr is deprecated after 1.6. but drupal (https://www.drupal.org/node/2416689) made some patch file for this but I am not getting how to use it, would you help me on this?@eisbehr